# Textbox Search & Return

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, wikipedia-api

I am trying to script a simple text box, So when a query is entered into it, It searches Wikipedia for that query and returns the result back to my website.

The part I am having some problems with is the Wikipedia API. I have tried using it and testing it out - But have failed.

If anybody could help me out or knows a tutorial site or anything that could help me, Ill be very greatfull.

Comment: What have you tried? If you want quicker/more accurate help, please post that code. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Wow, you can forget quicker, Chris Beemster was extraordinarily fast!

Comment: @11684 Thanks, I have just tried simple scripting using the Wikipedia API - But does not work, So trying to look for a site  or script that could help me out a little.

Comment: If you want us to properly help you, you need to tell us what exactly did you do and how did that fail. Otherwise, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score -1):

[This site](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code#Javascript) has quite some information. It contains a selection of links that explain you how to connect to the Wikipedia API through JavaScript.

Now, be very gratefull! ;)

Comment: Answers containing just a link are not very helpful. Could you include at least a summary of what the page says into your answer?